# Bitcoin transaction unconfirmed for 7 days

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I am new to Bitcoin (using Bitcoin core client) and I ticked the check box that said something like "send with 0 fee when possible". My transaction has been stuck in the unconfirmed status for 7 days and I don't know how to recall it to set a transaction fee. I searched Google and everything but they were guides for other Bitcoin clients and I'm scared of messing up and losing my coins. Can someone give a clear step by step on how to recall and add a transaction fee?

This is my transaction https://blockchain.info/address/19JL8rn56ZWGgqHibB4U11xqvc9pqdrykb

Answer (score 3):

After some time the network nodes will simply drop the transaction from memory. [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiU4b7ldKMs&feature=youtu.be&t=2829)

Comment: 72 hours then tx's get purged from the mempool if they have not been included in a block

Comment: If the cut-off is 72 hours then why would OPs transaction still show unconfirmed after 7 days? I'm having the same issue with a transfer that's been showing as unconfirmed for 5 days now. Nothing's been returned to my wallet, my client still says "Sending X bitcoins..." and blockchain.info still says Unconfirmed transaction. (Also worth noting, I set is as "Normal" for fees and priority.)

Answer (score 1):

Bitzuma wrote an article on how to double-spend your stuck transaction by increasing the fee using First-Seen-Safe, Replace By Fee(FSS-RBF). Instructions are step-by-step as you requested.

http://bitzuma.com/posts/how-to-clear-a-stuck-bitcoin-transaction/

The basic steps are:
1)  Re-create the original transaction using the same inputs. You can use coinb.in to create the raw transaction or you can create one manually.
2)  Increase the fee amount when creating the raw transaction.
3)  Sign the transaction with the private key.
4)  Re-broadcast the transaction using a node that will let you push signed transactions to the network https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_broadcasting

Also here's a youtube video going over the steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycq7O48aPvQ